# Does the SQL Transaction Log clear at the end of a loop?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, transaction

I'm running SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition. Every month, we run a stored procedure that loads millions of records with service dates going back five years. I have 400GB of space allocated across 4 data files, and 100GB of space allocated for the Log file. The job frequently fails because the Log file fills due to Active Transaction. The database is in the **simple recovery model**. So, I believe it should clear at the end of each transaction. The developer changed the job so that it loops through and loads the records one year at a time.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtDx;

SELECT ClaimHeader_ID
    ,ClaimDetail_ID
    ,ClaimServiceLine
    ,Unpvt.CodeLine
    ,Unpvt.DxCode 
INTO #UnpvtDx
FROM PRINCE.Claim.ClaimDetail det WITH (NOLOCK)
UNPIVOT 
(
    DxCode FOR CodeLine
    IN
    (
        Diagnosis1CD,Diagnosis2CD,Diagnosis3CD,Diagnosis4CD,Diagnosis5CD,
        Diagnosis6CD,Diagnosis7CD,Diagnosis8CD,Diagnosis9CD,
        Diagnosis10CD,Diagnosis11CD,Diagnosis12CD,Diagnosis13CD
    )
) as Unpvt ---53 secs
WHERE YEAR(ServiceFromDT) = @year;
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtPointer;

SELECT ClaimHeader_ID
    ,ClaimDetail_ID
    ,ClaimServiceLine
    ,Unpvt.CodeLine
    ,Unpvt.Pointer 
INTO #UnpvtPointer
FROM PRINCE.Claim.ClaimDetail det WITH (NOLOCK)
UNPIVOT 
(
    Pointer FOR CodeLine 
    IN (DiagPointer1,DiagPointer2,DiagPointer3,DiagPointer4)
) as Unpvt ---40 secs
WHERE YEAR(ServiceFromDT) = @year;
```

```
INSERT INTO PROD.Claim.ClaimDiag
(
    ClaimHeader_ID,ClaimDetail_ID,SourceID,EDWLoadDTS,PartnerCD,
    PartnerNM,ClaimID,ClaimServiceLine,ClaimStatus,CCOMemberID,
    MemberID,PlaceOfServiceCD,ServiceFromDT,ServiceToDT,ClaimForm,
    TypeOfBillCD,DiagnosisCD,DiagnosisDESC,DiagPointer
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    det.ClaimHeader_ID,det.ClaimDetail_ID,det.SourceID,det.EDWLoadDTS,
    det.PartnerCD,det.PartnerNM,det.ClaimID,det.ClaimServiceLine,
    det.ClaimStatus,det.CCOMemberID,det.MemberID,det.PlaceOfServiceCD,
    det.ServiceFromDT,det.ServiceToDT,det.ClaimForm,det.TypeOfBillCD,
    DiagnosisCD = dx.DxCode,
    DiagnosisDESC = diag.DiagnosisDESC,
    DiagPointer = point.Pointer
FROM PROD.Claim.ClaimDetail det WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PROD.Claim.ClaimHeader ch WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON ch.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
INNER JOIN #UnpvtDx dx
    ON dx.ClaimDetail_ID = det.ClaimDetail_ID
        AND dx.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
        AND dx.ClaimServiceLine = det.ClaimServiceLine
LEFT JOIN #UnpvtPointer point
    ON point.ClaimDetail_ID = det.ClaimDetail_ID
        AND point.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
        AND point.ClaimServiceLine = det.ClaimServiceLine
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reference.Reference.Diagnosis diag WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON dx.DxCode = diag.DiagnosisCD
        AND diag.ICDVersion = 'ICD10CM'
        AND diag.ActiveFLG = 1
WHERE YEAR(det.ServiceFromDT) = @year;
```

The stored procedure is executed from a SQL Agent job with this command:

```
DECLARE @year INT
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 

SELECT yr = YEAR(hdr.MinServiceFromDT)
FROM PROD.Claim.ClaimHeader hdr WITH (NOLOCK)   
GROUP BY YEAR(hdr.MinServiceFromDT)
ORDER BY YEAR(hdr.MinServiceFromDT)

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @year
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    EXEC Claim.sp_UpdateClaimDiag @year

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @year      
END 

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Is the end of a loop considered a transaction and therefore the log file should empty after every year of records is processed, or does the log file continue to fill until the job has iterated through every loop and loaded the records for all years?

I am also going to increase the Log file to 150GB, but that will max out the available space (without dropping below the 10% buffer).

Posting entire stored procedure code.

```
USE [Prod]
GO
    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
    
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
    
CREATE PROCEDURE [Claim].[sp_UpdateClaimDiag] @year INT
AS
    
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_DEFAULTS, ARITHABORT, NOCOUNT ON
    SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
    
    -- variable declaration
    DECLARE
        @transactional BIT
        , @trancount INT
        , @err INT
        , @procname SYSNAME
        , @error INT
        , @message VARCHAR(4000)
        , @xstate INT
        , @RecordCount int;
    
    SELECT @procname = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID()) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
        -- 0 =  no: will not execute batches inside a transaction; a partial success of procedure is possible
        -- 1 = yes: batches in procedure will be bound together by a transaction, partial success is impossible
        , @transactional = 0 
    
        -- optionally begin transaction and begin try block
        IF @transactional = 1 SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT

        BEGIN TRY
            IF @trancount = 0 and @transactional = 1
                BEGIN TRANSACTION

            ELSE IF @transactional = 1
                SAVE TRANSACTION p1
    
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ---Unpivot columns to Rows into Temp tables
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                
            ---ICD9CM  & ICD10CM
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtDx;

            SELECT
                ClaimHeader_ID
                ,ClaimDetail_ID
                ,ClaimServiceLine
                ,Unpvt.CodeLine
                ,Unpvt.DxCode 
            INTO #UnpvtDx
            FROM Prod.Claim.ClaimDetail det WITH (NOLOCK)
            UNPIVOT 
            (
                DxCode FOR CodeLine IN
                (
                    Diagnosis1CD,Diagnosis2CD,Diagnosis3CD,
                    Diagnosis4CD,Diagnosis5CD,Diagnosis6CD,
                    Diagnosis7CD,Diagnosis8CD,Diagnosis9CD,
                    Diagnosis10CD,Diagnosis11CD,Diagnosis12CD,
                    Diagnosis13CD
                )
            ) as Unpvt ---53 secs
            WHERE YEAR(ServiceFromDT) = @year;

            --Select top 100 * from #UnpvtDx where DxCode is null
    
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtPointer;

            SELECT
                ClaimHeader_ID
                ,ClaimDetail_ID
                ,ClaimServiceLine
                ,Unpvt.CodeLine
                ,Unpvt.Pointer 
            INTO #UnpvtPointer
            FROM Prod.Claim.ClaimDetail det WITH (NOLOCK)
            UNPIVOT 
            (
                Pointer FOR CodeLine IN
                (
                    DiagPointer1, DiagPointer2,
                    DiagPointer3,DiagPointer4
                )
            ) as Unpvt ---40 secs
            WHERE YEAR(ServiceFromDT) = @year;
    
            --Select top 100 * from #UnpvtPointer
                
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            --- INSERT INTO yearly records from the temp table
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
            INSERT INTO Prod.Claim.ClaimDiag (
                ClaimHeader_ID,
                ClaimDetail_ID,
                SourceID,
                EDWLoadDTS,
                PartnerCD,
                PartnerNM,
                ClaimID,
                ClaimServiceLine,
                ClaimStatus,
                CCOMemberID,
                MemberID,
                PlaceOfServiceCD,
                ServceFromDT,
                ServiceToDT,
                ClaimForm,
                TypeOfBillCD,
                DiagnosisCD,
                DiagnosisDESC,
                DiagPointer
            )
    
            SELECT DISTINCT
                det.ClaimHeader_ID,
                det.ClaimDetail_ID,
                det.SourceID,
                det.EDWLoadDTS,
                det.PartnerCD,
                det.PartnerNM,
                det.ClaimID,
                det.ClaimServiceLine,
                det.ClaimStatus,
                det.CCOMemberID,
                det.MemberID,
                det.PlaceOfServiceCD,
                det.ServiceFromDT,
                det.ServiceToDT,
                det.ClaimForm,
                det.TypeOfBillCD,
                DiagnosisCD = dx.DxCode,
                DiagnosisDESC = diag.DiagnosisDESC,
                DiagPointer = point.Pointer
            FROM Prod.Claim.ClaimDetail det WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Prod.Claim.ClaimHeader ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON ch.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
            INNER JOIN #UnpvtDx dx
                ON dx.ClaimDetail_ID = det.ClaimDetail_ID
                    AND dx.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
                    AND dx.ClaimServiceLine = det.ClaimServiceLine
            LEFT JOIN #UnpvtPointer point
                ON point.ClaimDetail_ID = det.ClaimDetail_ID
                    AND point.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
                    AND point.ClaimServiceLine = det.ClaimServiceLine
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Reference.Reference.Diagnosis diag WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON dx.DxCode = diag.DiagnosisCD
                    AND diag.ICDVersion = 'ICD10CM'
                    AND diag.ActiveFLG = 1
            WHERE YEAR(det.ServiceFromDT) = @year
                --AND Year(det.ServiceFromDT) = 2021--for testing
                --and det.ClaimID ='21006E06455'--for testing
    
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            --insert into updatelog table
            SET @RecordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
    
            DECLARE @procName1 SYSNAME
            SET @procName1 = @procname + ' ' + CAST(@year AS varchar(4))
            INSERT INTO Prod.dbo.UpdateLog(EventTimestamp,EventDescription,ProcName,TableName)
            SELECT GETDATE(),
                'Inserted ' + CAST(@RecordCount AS varchar(100)) + ' records',
                @procName1,
                'Claim.ClaimDiag'
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtDx
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtPointer
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            SPEXIT:

            IF @transactional = 1 and @trancount = 0 COMMIT
        END TRY

        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- error handling with catch
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE()
            IF @transactional = 1 and @xstate = -1 ROLLBACK
            IF @transactional = 1 and @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0 ROLLBACK
            IF @transactional = 1 and @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION p1
        
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #claims
            SET @procName1 = @procname + ' ' + CAST(@year AS varchar(4)) ---+ ', ' + CAST(@month AS varchar(4)) 
    
            RAISERROR ('%s, Error %d, %s', 16, 1, @procname1, @error, @message) 
            RETURN @error
        END CATCH
    
        RETURN 0  
    END
    GO
```

Comment: Under Simple recovery model, truncation occurs after a checkpoint (with several considerations).  It does not automatcially truncate after a single transaction.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You'd have to provide the full block of code you're executing for us to know when the transaction ends. There are implicate and explicit transactions.

Comment: `YEAR(det.ServiceFromDT) = @year` That is not sargable either. Use proper lower and upper boundaries to take advangtage of any useful indexes.

Comment: Updated to include full code and command.

Comment: I don't see any transactions here at all. So all commands will execute in their own separate transaction, unless there is an outer `BEGIN TRANSACTION` over the whole procedure. In `SIMPLE` recovery, under certain circumstances it may be worth doing an explicit `CHECKPOINT`, but it won't help if the transaction is still open

Comment: @Charlieface - There actually is a 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' at the top. Apologies for not including that. I was trying to monitor as it executed on a Test server and it does appear that the log is clearing at times, so I'm guessing it's at the end of the year being processed. 


`IF @transactional = 1 SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT
 BEGIN TRY
  IF @trancount = 0 and @transactional = 1 BEGIN TRANSACTION
  ELSE IF @transactional = 1 SAVE TRANSACTION p1`

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey - Added everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `SIMPLE RECOVERY` model, the transaction log is truncated at each checkpoint. Not necessarily at the end of your transaction. Checkpoints happen every 60 seconds.

Looking at the below section of your code, you're not actually explicitly starting  transaction at all. You initially `set @transactional = 0`, and then only start a transaction if `@transactional = 1`. Also, you're only setting `@trancount` to a value here based on the `IF` statement. The `BEGIN TRY` block still starts, since you do not have a `BEGIN/END` block following the `IF` statement. This is not your problem though, it just means you're doing implicit transactions each time, instead of creating an explicit transaction.

```
SELECT @procname = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID()) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
    -- 0 =  no: will not execute batches inside a transaction; a partial success of procedure is possible
    -- 1 = yes: batches in procedure will be bound together by a transaction, partial success is impossible
    , @transactional = 0 
    
    -- optionally begin transaction and begin try block
    IF @transactional = 1 SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT

    BEGIN TRY
        IF @trancount = 0 and @transactional = 1
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

        ELSE IF @transactional = 1
            SAVE TRANSACTION p1
```

I'd suspect that even at a years worth of data at a time, you're generating more transaction log throughput than your drive can support. How much space is one year worth of data taking up in this table?

Consider dropping your batch size from a year to a month and see if that helps. While you're at it, stop surrounding your date column with a YEAR() function. This makes those columns non-SARGABLE, which means SQL Server cannot use any existing index when retrieving the data. This could be causing your transaction to run longer than needed, and thus causing other inflight transactions to be retained in the log while this transaction runs.

Consider the below changes to your stored procedure. I simplified it down a bit to highlight the important parts to be changed. You'll need to merge it with what you have and test it. This makes it easier to control your batch size when you call the procedure.

Also, I removed the `NOLOCK` hints. Read more [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/) to understand why that's a bad idea. You likely thought you needed the `NOLCOK` hints because of the non-SARGABLE where clauses.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Claim].[sp_UpdateClaimDiag]
    @Interval int = 30
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @MinServiceFromDT DATETIME
        @MaxServiceFromDT DATETIME,
        @NextServiceFromDT DATETIME;

    SELECT
        @MinServiceFromDT = MIN(hdr.MinServiceFromDT),
        @MaxServiceFromDT = MAX(hdr.MinServiceFromDT)
    FROM PROD.Claim.ClaimHeader;

    WHILE @MinServiceFromDT <= @MaxServiceFromDT
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            @NextServiceFromDT = DATEADD(day,@Interval,@MinServiceFromDT);

            ---ICD9CM  & ICD10CM
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtDx;

            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #UnpvtPointer;
    
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            ---Unpivot columns to Rows into Temp tables
            --------------------------------------------------------------

            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            SELECT ClaimHeader_ID, ...
            INTO #UnpvtDx
            FROM Prod.Claim.ClaimDetail det
            UNPIVOT 
            (
                DxCode FOR CodeLine IN
                (
                    Diagnosis1CD,...
                )
            ) as Unpvt
            WHERE ServiceFromDT >= @MinServiceFromDT
                AND ServiceFromDT < @NextServiceFromDT;

            SELECT ClaimHeader_ID, ...
            INTO #UnpvtPointer
            FROM Prod.Claim.ClaimDetail det
            UNPIVOT 
            (
                Pointer FOR CodeLine IN
                (
                    DiagPointer1, DiagPointer2,
                    DiagPointer3,DiagPointer4
                )
            ) as Unpvt
            WHERE ServiceFromDT >= @MinServiceFromDT
                AND ServiceFromDT < @NextServiceFromDT;
            
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            --- INSERT INTO yearly records from the temp table
            --------------------------------------------------------------
        
            INSERT INTO Prod.Claim.ClaimDiag
                (ClaimHeader_ID, ....)
            SELECT DISTINCT det.ClaimHeader_ID, ....
            FROM Prod.Claim.ClaimDetail det WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN Prod.Claim.ClaimHeader ch WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON ch.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
            INNER JOIN #UnpvtDx dx
                ON dx.ClaimDetail_ID = det.ClaimDetail_ID
                    AND dx.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
                    AND dx.ClaimServiceLine = det.ClaimServiceLine
            LEFT JOIN #UnpvtPointer point
                ON point.ClaimDetail_ID = det.ClaimDetail_ID
                    AND point.ClaimHeader_ID = det.ClaimHeader_ID
                    AND point.ClaimServiceLine = det.ClaimServiceLine
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Reference.Reference.Diagnosis diag
                ON dx.DxCode = diag.DiagnosisCD
                    AND diag.ICDVersion = 'ICD10CM'
                    AND diag.ActiveFLG = 1
            WHERE det.ServiceFromDT >= @MinServiceFromDT
                AND det.ServiceFromDT < @NextServiceFromDT;

            --------------------------------------------------------------
            --insert into updatelog table

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

            SET @ MinServiceFromDT = @NextServiceFromDT
        END TRY

        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- error handling with catch
        BEGIN CATCH
            <do error handling stuff>
        END CATCH
    END
END
GO
```